# Querying data by empty json or with error data

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in Postgresql that have a jsonb column. This column can have 3 types of data, in the following structure:

1. `[]` if the result is empty;
2. `[{"items": [{"name": "item1", "value": "value1", "messages": []}]}]"`
3. `[{"items": [{"name": "error", "value": "some error", "messages": []}]}]`

If the first item is not an error, I have to show the data. And also I have an interface to get all the errors.
I'm using a `COUNT WHERE FILTER` to get the counting of empty and errors and it is working.

This is the example query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.my_column = '[]' OR items -> 'items' -> 0 ->> 'name' = 'error') --This works
FROM my_table t1
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(CAST(t1.my_column AS jsonb)) AS items ON TRUE
```

But when I try to use it on another query, it returns `cannot extract elements from an object`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.column1, ...
FROM my_table t1
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(CAST(t1.my_column AS jsonb)) AS items ON TRUE
WHERE t1.my_column <> '[]' --This works
OR items -> 'items' -> 0 ->> 'name' <> 'error' --This doesn't
```

It seems it cannot extract data from an empty array, but I actually don't know how to make it work for both cases.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if the column is already a jsonb, then why the `cast(t1.my_column AS jsonb)`?

Comment: What exactly is the output you are after?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name from this second query: getting all of my data where this column does not have an empty json array or does not have the first item with name error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query references the alias for the table (a "record"), not the actual value that is returned by `jsonb_array_elements`.

You need to change that to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t1.my_column) with ordinality AS items(item) ON true
where item.item -> 'items' -> 0 ->> 'name' <> 'error'
```

Note that the where condition on the outer joined table turns your outer join back into an inner join. It's effectively the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table t1
  JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t1.my_column) AS items(item) 
    ON items.item -> 'items' -> 0 ->> 'name' <> 'error'
```

Comment: Could test your second example. The first one is returning the same error message. I guess it can't extract the data from empty json.